# How do I make my Expo EAS app only track a user's background location in certain screens?

Tags: javascript, react-native, geolocation, expo, location

I have a RN/EAS app that tracks a user's background location. I only want their background location to be logged in certain screens, but whenever I have the app engaged in any screen, I get the blue, background location tracking notice.

I have my task manager existing in the App.js folder, but I am unsure how I may properly configure it to only run in certain screens. Below is my TaskManager code:

```
const LOCATION_TASK_NAME = 'background-location-task'

TaskManager.defineTask('firstTask', ({data, error}) => {
   if(error){
      alert('Something went wrong with background locations')
   }

  if(data){
    alert('Something went right with background locations')
    const{locations} = data
    console.log(locations, 'locations')
  }

  })
```